# Python: Change format of np.array or allow tolerance in in1d function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, intersection

I have two numpy arrays (data files loaded with `np.loadtxt`). They do not have the same length (or number of rows if you will).

I want to create a mask, where I find the values in the smaller array in the larger array. For that I can use `np.in1d`. However, the precision on the larger array is larger as well. My problem is illustrated in the following example

```
a = np.array([1.011, 2.000, 3.001])
b = np.array([1.01, 3.00])
mask = np.in1d(a, b)

c
array([False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

What I want is `c` to be

```
c
array([True, False, True], dtype=bool)
```

So is there a way to either allow `np.in1d` to allow a tolerance (`tol=0.01`) or change the precision on array `a`? I am also open to other solutions of cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it as shown below.  If `a` and `b` get large, this is going to need lots of memory (on the order of the product of the sizes of a and b).  Maybe you could loop over into small-enough chunks of b if that's a problem.

```
import numpy as np

def in1d_tol(a,b,tol):
    d=np.abs(a-b[:,np.newaxis])
    return np.any(d<=tol, axis=0)

a = np.array([1.011, 2.000, 3.001])
b = np.array([1.01, 3.00])

c = in1d_tol(a,b,0.01)

print c
```

Comment: That does the job. I will wait and see if there comes anything else. For the information (and hopefully comparison with other solutions), this takes 663ms for my data. Thanks for the answer so far.